# Does there exist a field where all even degree equations have solutions but not all odd degree equations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Does there exist a field $F$, preferably a subfield of the complex numbers, such that all even degree polynomial equations have solutions in $F$, but such that for every positive odd integer $k$ greater than or equal to $3$, there exist $k$-th degree polynomial equations which do not have solutions in $F$? Basically, such a field $F$, if it exists, would be an "anti"-real-closed field. In a real closed field, every odd degree polynomial equation has solutions, but for every positive even integer $k$, there exist $k$-th degree polynomial equations with no solutions.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of odd degree with no solution, then $f(x)^2$ will be a polynomial of even degree with no solution. So probably you want to restrict to only irreducible even-degree polynomials?

Comment: Well, it should be noted that a polynomial of degree $0$ never has **roots**.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask instead if there is a field where every even-degree polynomial is reducible, but there exists at least one irreducible odd-degree polynomial of degree $>1$. (Ask in a separate question, since this question already contains answers for the question as-is.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. Suppose that every polynomial over $F$ of even degree has a root in $F$, and pick $p \in F[x]$ of odd degree. Then, $\deg (p^2)$ is even, so $p(\alpha)^2 = 0$ for some $\alpha \in F$. But that means that $p(\alpha) = 0$, so in particular the arbitrary polynomial $p$ of odd degree has a root in $F$.

As @Ron Kaminsky remarked in the comments, there's an informally dual argument: Instead consider the polynomial $q(x) := p(x^2)$. It has even degree $2 \deg p$ so has a root $\alpha \in F$, that is, $0 = q(\alpha) = p(\alpha^2)$, hence $\alpha^2 \in F$ is a root of $p$.

Comment: Doesn't this also work in a kind of dual fashion since $p(x^2)$ also has even degree? Is there some kind of interesting mathematics behind this "duality'?

Comment: @RonKaminsky your argument is more general. In an arbitrary ring, $\deg(p^2)$ and $2\deg(p)$ are typically unequal, whereas $\deg(p(x^2)) = 2\deg(p(x))$ always, so there is not even a *ring* with this property.

Comment: @RonKaminsky Yes, and that's a nice observation. Why not add that as separate answer? (If you'd prefer not to, I'm happy to add it to my own.) Offhand I don't see any deeper explanation connecting the two arguments.

Comment: @Anton "deg(p2)
 and 2deg(p)
 are typically unequal" Is that for non-domains?

Comment: @Accumulation Yes; e.g., in $\Bbb Z_4$, $\deg (2 x + 1) = 1$ and $\deg (2 \cdot x^2 + 1) = 2 \cdot 1$ but $\deg [(2 x + 1)^2] = \deg 1 = 0 \neq 2 \cdot 1$.

Comment: Travis Willse, please add it to your answer, however, note that @Anton's observation, while interesting, doesn't ring true to me, since not all elements of arbitrary rings have square roots. And since the question does ask about arbitrary fields, my observation is also incorrect in general.

Comment: @RonKaminsky I'm not sure I see the problem with your observation: Given any $p \in F[x]$ of odd degree, $q(x) := p(x^2)$ has even degree. So, there is some $\alpha \in F$ such that $q(\alpha) = 0$, or, in terms of $p$, $p(\alpha^2) = 0$, and in particular $p$ has a root ($\alpha^2$).

Comment: If $R$ is a ring such that all even-degree polynomials in $R[x]$ have roots, all elements *do* have square roots: For any $r \in R$ there is a root $\alpha \in R$ of the (even-degree) polynomial $x^2 - r$; rearranging gives $\alpha^2 = r$, i.e., $\alpha$ is a square root of $r$.

Comment: Thanks, Travis, I missed that the assumptions of the question preclude fields without square roots! So it would please me for you to add my observation to your answer. It certainly was inspired by it!

Comment: @Anton All we need for the original argument is that $\deg (p^2) \equiv 0 \pmod 2$. Is that still true for polynomial rings $R[x]$ over all rings $R$?

Comment: @TravisWillse Certainly not, for example R = Z/9Z has (3x + 1)^2 = 6x + 1 is not of even degree, but we have the additional issue that p(a)^2 = 0 doesn't imply p(a) = 0 in general.

Comment: @Anton Ah yes, of course!

Answer (score 5):

While I can't guarantee that such a field exists, I can guarantee you a field such that nothing other than $0,1,2$ or $2^n$ degree polynomials irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ have solutions: the field of constructible numbers. I think that'll be as good as you can get.

Comment: @TravisWillse thanks for the heads up mate; I've amended it :)